# why function rbind.data.frame behave different in do.call

Tags: r, dataframe, do.call

I have a question about do.call, pretty strange

**1. What I trying to do**

I am trying to bind many data frames into one single data frame, all the data frames are in a list t3, you may see the pic below:

[image: list variable t3]

**2. Methods**

2.1 the one works

`t4 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, t3)`

2.2 not works

`t4 <- rbind.data.frame(t3)`

The error message is below:

[image: error message]

**3. question**

I think rbind.data.frame would behave same if I remove do.call, why it only works if I am using do.call? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `do.call(FUN, list)` was designed to accept a input function `FUN` along with a *list* input `list`.  It applies the function to each element in the list and then aggregates the results.

In your call

```
t4 <- rbind.data.frame(t3)
```

You are trying to `rbind` a list of a data frames, when the `rbind.data.frame` function is expecting a *single* data frame instead of `t3` as input.

You could use `rbind.data.frame` without `do.call` if you wanted to.  Assuming you had only 5 elements in list `t3`, then the following should work:

```
t4 <- rbind.data.frame(t3[[1]], t3[[2]], t3[[3]], t3[[4]], t3[[5]])
```

As you can see, this will get to be tedious (and not readable) quickly.  This is the advantage of using `do.call()`.